# Sitemap does not appear to work on .Net Core

Tags: sitemappath

SiteMapPath .Net component works fine on .Net environment. But it seems not on .Net Core. 
For e.g., if the https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2f59d0/implementing-sitemap-in-Asp-Net/ is developed choosing .Net Core, the breadcrumps as expected do not show up.

But I couldn't find any official doc from Microsoft on that. Does any one know.

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: If your question is what I tried that didn't work then was to implement [this example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2f59d0/implementing-sitemap-in-Asp-Net/) but in a .net core project using asp.net web form.

Comment: Else if you wanted to know about the solution implemented, then I hard coded it as there were only about 12 pages, though not very elegant from a developer's point of view !!